# \tl_gput_right:Nx with argument containing \par causing error after a list

Tags: macros, errors, expl3

I accidentally ran into this issue and don't understand why this happens. Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

%% OK
Text
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_gput_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \par }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%% Error
\begin{itemize}
    \item text.
\end{itemize}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_gput_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \par }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

I'm simply putting something (containing `\par`) in an irrelevant macro, but why does it produce an error when following a list?

To be specific, the error is

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\@restorepar ->\def \par 
                         {\@par }
l.16 \tl_gput_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \par }
```

Comment: If you really need to use `x`-expansion, use `\exp_not:N \par`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after a list (or section headigs) `\par` is not the tex primive but a macro that is used to set up the paragraph shape after the first paragraph.

It is not safe to use in an `\edef` or `x` argument expansion.

Comment: Thank you, I get it. I shall modify my code to avoid putting `\par` inside a `x`-type expansion.

Comment: @Jinwen more to to the point you should seriously look at each and every x-type in your code and ask yourself if it is actually the right thing to do. 99% of the time it isn't and 100% not if the argument receives arbitrary user (aka document-level) data.